# Httpconnection won't open a link properly

Tags: android, httpconnection

I have an app, which is quite simple. In preparation for a dictionary it is supposed to take words and enter it in a database. The entering part is done by a php script, which works fine. The link that is produced works as well, I tried it manually. May I ask, what I have overseen in this code, as I haven't found anything considering the topic on Google:

```
    private class SendData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(uri.toString());
            EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.oshikwanyamaEx);
            text.setText(url.toString());
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.connect();
        }catch (MalformedURLException m){
            m.printStackTrace();
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            if (urlConnection != null){
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data was sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance
This is the PHP code:

```
<?php 

    //Creating a connection
    $con = mysqli_connect("breidinga.lima-db.de:3306","USER373834","*********","db_373834_1");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
       echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    } 
    //INSERT INTO `ENGOKY` (`_id`, `eng`, `oky`, `type`, `engex`, `okyex`, `okypl`, `engpl`) VALUES (NULL, '', '', '', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `ENGOKY` (`_id`, `eng`, `oky`, `type`, `engex`, `okyex`, `okypl`, `engpl`) VALUES (NULL,'".$_GET["eng"]."', '";
    //$sql = $sql.$_GET["oky"]."', '".$_GET["type"]."', '".$_GET["engex"]."', '".$_GET["okyex"]."', '".$_GET["okyex"]."', '".$_GET["ekypl"]."', '".$_GET["engpl"]."')";
$sql = $sql.$_GET["oky"]."', '".$_GET["type"]."', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)";
  $sql = str_replace("''","NULL", $sql);
    mysqli_query($con ,$sql);
    mysqli_free_result($result);
    mysqli_close($con);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little improvement to your code and some more declaration

```
        URL url = new URL("your URL here");

        JSONObject postDataParams = new JSONObject();
        postDataParams.put("word", "onomatopoeia"); //Change #1
        Log.e("params",postDataParams.toString());

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(15000); //Change #2
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000); //Change #2
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

         OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
```

1 - You need to pass in the parameters into your PHP file as I can't see any evidence of anything being passed in. 
Assuming the variable is similar to the follow: -

```
$word= $_POST['word'];
```

2 - Always useful to set the connection timeout and read timeout as this will terminate the request after some time. In this case, it's 15 seconds.

3 - As a guidance, just make sure there is a return response from the PHP file as you want to make sure if your insertion was successful or not.

4 - Add the following permission, may make a difference

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

5 - Read the response code from the connection and this will determine if it even bothered doing anything.

```
int response = conn.getResponseCode();
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Response code is: " + response);

        if ((response >= 200) && (response < 300)) {
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "The response is: " + conn.getResponseMessage());
        }
```

6. User receiving response code 301 (Redirection) and add this line to stop getting redirected

```
conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
```

Comment: I entered the parameters in a step beforehand:

Comment: Yes, I have it activated Internet permission

Comment: I did that. It worked once and no second time. The Code it prints is 301

Comment: 301 is the redirection response code. This clarifies that the application is communicating with the URL successfully *horray*. Now it depends on how you are dealing with this server side. Share the PHP script?

Comment: OK hold that, I think someone was trying out the link. It showed up in the database. It wasn't the app that worked

Comment: Here is the php code. But it should work, because if I take the link generated by the code and enter it via chrome, the entry pops up in the db

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180966/discussion-between-nero-and-adrian-breiding).